# SQLDependency OnChange event producing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub, sqldependency

I have a problem when using `SQLDependency` and SignalR Hub. When a connection with the hub is started, the `SQLDependency`'s `OnChange` event is always firing even though there are no changes in the database.

Here is my code that contains `SQLDependency`

```cs
public List<NotifCenterModel> countNewTransaksi()
{
    List<NotifCenterModel> ncms = new List<NotifCenterModel>();
    command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Edolpuz_DB.dbo.TABEL_NOTIF_CENTER.NAMA_TABEL,Edolpuz_DB.dbo.TABEL_NOTIF_CENTER.JUMLAH_NOTIF FROM Edolpuz_DB.dbo.TABEL_NOTIF_CENTER",connect);
    try 
    {
        command.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
        if(connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connect.Close();
        connect.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ncms.Add(new NotifCenterModel(reader[0].ToString(), int.Parse(reader[1].ToString())));
        }
        return ncms;
    }
    catch { return null; }
    finally { connect.Close(); }
}

private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    TransHub.Show();   
}
```

and in my Hub the code is like this

```cs
public class TransHub : Hub
{
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TransHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
}
```

and here is my javascript

```js
 $(function () {
            // Proxy created on the fly
            var job = $.connection.transHub;
            // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
            job.client.displayStatus = function () {
                //     alert("test");
                getData();
            };

            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                getData();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });

        });

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: server + '/Admin/GetNotifikasi/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++)
            {
                if (data[i].nama_tabel == "TABEL_TRANSAKSI")
                {    
                    $('#notifTrans').text(data[i].jumlah_notif);
                }
                else if (data[i].nama_tabel == "TABEL_KONF_BAYAR")
                {
                    $('#notifBayar').text(data[i].jumlah_notif);
                }
                else if (data[i].nama_tabel == "TABEL_TESTI")
                {
                    $('#notifTesti').text(data[i].jumlah_notif);
                }
                else if (data[i].nama_tabel == "TABEL_KUSTOM_ORDER")
                {
                    $('#notifKustom').text(data[i].jumlah_notif);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When in `connection.hub.start().done` I call `getData()`, it will constantly fire and produce an infinite loop, but when I don't call `getData()` it doesn't fire the event when data in table changes. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

In `dependency_OnChange`, you need to check `e.Type`. If it's `!= SqlNotificationType.Change`, then the handler was called for some reason other than a data change. The subscription itself likely failed.

Comment: But when i check e.Type first, it don't give any result even though database is change. What's wrong with my code ? @jjj

Comment: @HandaruEriPramudiya; You were saying that the "`OnChange` event is always firing even though there are no changes" -- for a single subscription, you will only notified at most once, so whenever `dependency_OnChange` is called, the subscription is no longer active. But if it's called with `e.Type == SqlNotifcationType.Subscribe`, then the subscription failed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aewzkxxh(v=vs.90)), the table name in query must be two-part name, like [dbo].[TABEL_NOTIF_CENTER].

> The projected columns in the SELECT statement must be explicitly stated, and table names must be qualified with two-part names. Notice that this means that all tables referenced in the statement must be in the same database.

[]'s